# How to check via Yup if input is mail or username?

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I have a field that I want to validate if it is a username or a mail address. I am using Yup for validation but having trouble setting up the correct Yup schema.

If the input is neither a mail address nor a username the validation should fail. In other words, one of the two conditions must be met to pass validation.

```
let schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email(), 
});
```

```
// username pattern
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9._]{5,25}$)[^_.].*[^_.]$/);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify and perform validation, u can use the following shape for your field in Yup:

```js
Yup.string()
  .required('Required Field')
  .test('is-email', 'Invalid email', (value) => {
    if (value) {
      return value.includes('@') ? Yup.string().email().isValidSync(value) : true
  }
  return true
}),
```

> You can add your regex to the username in the same way, using the .test method